# Is it possible that REMOTE_ADDR could be blank?

Tags: php, networking, webserver

As far as I'm aware, the webserver (Apache/Nginx) provides the (`$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`) based on the claimed location of the requesting user agent. So I understand they can be lying, but is it possible that this value could be blank? Would the network interface or webserver even accept a request without a correctly formed IP?

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: you can't lie about where you want the data sent back to... TCP needs to know your IP to send packets to you, so before they can even send an HTTP request the TCP connection must have sent a SYN/ACK to the IP in order for the connection to be created...

Comment: You can most certainly lie about where you want the data sent back to. That is the problem with some forms of DoS attacks.

Comment: @Xeoncross: a DoS attack with source spoofing wouldn't get as far as Apache - the networking stack would be stuck with the connection in a half-open state (as there's no way to reliably generate `SYN/ACK` without the `ACK`) - that's even the point of many DoS spoofed attacks: the table for half-open connection used to be *tiny* on some systems and they stopped accepting once it was filled. Anyway, even if you managed to somehow open a TCP connection with a spoofed source address, all you'd see would be a *different* REMOTE_ADDR, not an empty one.

Comment: @Piskvor thanks for the clarification. I was still thinking about older systems with small connection pools.

Comment: @tobyodavies, TCP does have that information but not in $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']. That's an *HTTP* header. The HTTP header can be forged, or lie, or in practice be non-RFC-compliant.

Comment: @EJP: No, `REMOTE_ADDR` (and `REMOTE_PORT`) is supplied by the local web server based on the remote address of the connected socket, it's not from a HTTP header.  You may be thinking of `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']`.

Comment: I've seen `REMOTE_ADDR` come up as `"unknown"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is theoretically possible, as the matter is up to the http server or at least the corresponding PHP SAPI.

In practice, I haven't encountered such a situation, except with the CLI SAPI.

EDIT: For Apache, it would seem this is always set, as `ap_add_common_vars` always adds it to the table that ends up being read by the Apache module PHP SAPI (disclaimer: I have very limited knowledge of Apache internals).

If using PHP in a CGI environment, the specification in RFC 3875 seems to guarantee the existence of this variable:

```
4.1.8.  REMOTE_ADDR

   The REMOTE_ADDR variable MUST be set to the network address of the
   client sending the request to the server.
```

Comment: That was my theory also, given that the CLI SAPI isn't handled by a webserver - it's possible that the value might not be populated. However, I want to make sure that Apache/Nginx or the network ALWAYS pass a value for the IP - or just drop the request.

Comment: @Xeon Then this question is about Apache, not PHP and you should tag it as such. And I suppose it could make a difference whether you're using CGI or the apache module.

Comment: Actually, I don't use Apache - I use Nginx. Also, as stated in the question I'm open to the network interface, the webserver, or anything else blocking the request if that keeps PHP from being called with an empty REMOTE_ADDR.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. I currently see values of "unknown" in my logs of Apache-behind-Nginx, for what looks like a normal request/response sequence  in the logs. I believe this is possible because `mod_extract_forwarded` is modifying the request to reset REMOTE_ADDR based on data in the `X-Forwarded-For` header. So, the original `REMOTE_ADDR` value was likely valid, but as part of passing through our reverse proxy and Apache, `REMOTE_ADDR` appears invalid by the time it arrives at the application.

If you have installed Perl's `libwww-perl`, you can test this situation like this (changing example.com to be your own domain or application):

```
HEAD -H 'X-Forwarded-For: ' -sSe http://www.example.com/
HEAD -H 'X-Forwarded-For: HIMOM' -sSe http://www.example.com/
HEAD -H 'X-Forwarded-For: <iframe src=http://example.com>' -sSe http://www.example.com/
```

( You can also use any other tool that allows you to handcraft HTTP requests with custom request headers. )

Now, go check your access logs to see what values they logged, and check your applications to see how they handled the bad input. `

Comment: That's scary: replacing canonical information (`REMOTE_ADDR`) with user-supplied (`X-FORWARDED-FOR`).  Your analysis sounds correct, though: "unknown" is a [valid identifier](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7239#section-6.2), and nginx was probably just pulling it out of the list per its [old proxy header scanning logic](http://serverfault.com/a/414166/204816).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's reserved but writable. I've seen badly written apps that were scribbling all over the superglobals - could the script be overwriting it, e.g. with `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '';`?

Other than that, even if the request were proxied, there should be the address of the proxy - could it be some sort of internal-rewrite module messing with it (`mod_rewrite` allows internal redirects, not sure if it affects this)?

Comment: It's never happened to me (that I know of) however, I want to make sure I write my code to handle an empty value if it's possible.

Comment: @Xeoncross: I'd say it's a certain indication of invalid program state and hint of possible further state corruption. It's unlikely to encounter this in the wild, though.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be blank, and nothing can't connect to your web service. Whatever's connecting must have an IP address to send and receive data. Whether that IP address can be trusted is a different matter.